# Center Button with HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to center the button below - I have tried from other examples altering CSS code or using text-align: center but neither options have worked. I know the code itself can be fixed but I am quite a newbie so any tips would help.

Thanks

```
<a class="btn-group" 
 style="color: #ffffff;" 
 href="http://requestgoods.com/item-request/">Request Goods Now</a></button>
```

Comment: Center the button how? In a div? On the page? You need to explain more

Comment: Sorry - i am trying to center the button on the page, apologies again

Comment: Put that into the question. Maybe provide a fiddle aswell.

Comment: Apologies all! First time using this (should have outlined the question more clearly). I will clarify for future posts and thanks for the feedback. Ehsans answer was what i wanted :)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button><a class="btn-group"  style="color: #000"  href="http://requestgoods.com/item-request/">Request Goods Now</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one outer div and set `text-align : center` to this div.

use this Code :

```html
<div style = "text-align: center;">
  <button>
    <a class="btn-group" href="http://requestgoods.com/item-request/">Request Goods Now</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is different my code and your code? you only convert my code to inline  style.

Comment: you tried text-align :  center on button its not working ...if you take div and set center then and then it goes center of that div.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

HTML

```
<div>
<button>
<a class="btn-group" 
 style="color: #ffffff;" 
 href="http://requestgoods.com/item-request/">Request Goods Now</a>
</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    text-align:center;
}
```